# Не ставится PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Сегодня захотелось мне написать кое-что на PyQt5, всё работало, но designer я, видимо за старостью лет (или кто-то из других пользователей ПК), удалил, поставил PyQt из установщика, всё появилось, всё заработало, но вот проблема, КОД с PyQt не работает, даже официальные примеры, выходит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/myStealer/main.py", line 1, in <module>
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найдена указанная процедура.
```

при этом просто `import PyQt5` работает исправно, переустановка PyQt с удалением его путём `pip unsinstall pyqt5` не помогает, поискал вопросы на stackoverflow - не помогло.

Версия python -3.6.1 ОС - windows 7 x32

P.S в pyCharm все модули PyQt5 индексируются

Comment: глупый вопрос при чем тут он?  если импортировать на пример просто `import PyQt5` то все работает, и вопрос был не о pyCharm'е который прекрасно работает, а о том, что питон не видит PyQt

Comment: А через IDLE Python пример работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я разобрался сам, итак: 
1) Связана ошибка видимо с тем, что при удалении через `pip uninstall pyqt5` выходило 2 ошибки: 1) почему-то удалялись только файлы pyqt а вот сама папка PyQt5 (лежит в 'путь до python.exe'/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5) оставалась на месте, из-за чего PyCharm считал, что такой модуль есть, просто он пустой, к тому же полазив я обнаружил что сам PyCharm кэширует некоторые файлы и модули (у меня были: flask, django, PyQt5, kivy)

2) Переустановка не помогала, видимо из-за того, что папка PyQt5 есть, и поэтому pip говорил, что уже все итак стоит

3) лечил так: удалил папку PyQt5, удалил кэш в PyCharm у меня было `путь до PyCharm/system/-цифры` вот папку "-цифры" я удалил, после установил с установщика: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/ во время установки сменил путь (стандартно ставит в C:/python35), а python 3.6 лежит обыччно либо в `C:/program files/python36-32 либо C:/program files/python/python36-32` либо в `C:\Users\<имя пользователя>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\` вот вам нужно поставить 1 из этих путей